# Turn off jack audio controls using ALSA configuration file

Tags: linux, audio, alsa

My audio player recently went nuts and randomly switches audio tracks during playback when I'm using it in motion. After a brief investigation I have discovered that the headphone jack is a cause of mentioned problem - seems that due to some unknown electrical issues the player thinks it is receiving the phantom signals from the non-existing play/pause buttons on the headset, using the electrical protocol described [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/242883/how-do-media-buttons-on-a-plain-wired-headset-work).

While I have no good ideas how to fix the glitch on the hardware level, I have got and idea how to solve this using software - try to turn off headset controls entirely through player's sound card configuration. I have no such buttons on my headphones and have no plans to use them ever.

The player is Cayin N3, it is bundled with AK4490 sound chip. The player uses custom Linux-based firmware and the sound subsystem is ALSA. Seems that player's main userspace GUI application directly talks with ALSA subsystem through `libasound` gateway library.

I want to configure the player's sound card through `asound.conf` or something similar to completely turn off the headset controls, so the userspace app will not receive any callbacks, induced by phantom electrical signals.

Any ideas how to implement this? Not an expert in ALSA, not sure where to start. The only thing I have found is [how ALSA maps jack controls to userspace](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/sound/designs/jack-controls.html), but have no clue how this can help.